# Flex item width is being respected instead of shrinking

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm self-teaching myself CSS using The Odin Project.

See here for the code I'm working on:
https://codepen.io/Ashwin-Parcha/pen/JjxxJJq

Problem
I've set a `width` on the flex items cards (`.card`) that is too wide on purpose at `400px`. These cards have default `flex` values of `0 1 auto`. From my understanding, when the flex-basis is auto, the width is considered, but if the total width of the flex items is bigger than the parent and flex-shrink = 1, then the width isn't respected and the items will shrink to fit the container. But as you can see, the width IS being respected here for some reason.

Expected Outcome
The width shouldn't be respected and cards should shrink.

Thanks for your help!

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 72px;
  background: darkmagenta;
  color: white;
}

.footer {
  height: 72px;
  background: #eee;
  color: darkmagenta;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  background: royalblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 400px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.hoflex {
  display: flex;
  margin: 16px;
  gap: 12px;
}

.fullflex {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
      MY AWESOME WEBSITE
    </div>
    
    <div class="fullflex">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">⭐ - link one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">‍♂️ - link two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">️ - link three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> - link four</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="hoflex">
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, eveniet? Dolorem dignissimos maiores non delectus possimus dolor nulla repudiandae vitae provident quae, obcaecati ipsam unde impedit corrupti veritatis minima porro?</div>
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi quaerat qui iure ipsam maiores velit tempora, deleniti nesciunt fuga suscipit alias vero rem, corporis officia totam saepe excepturi odit ea.</div>
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer">
      The Odin Project ❤️
    </div>
```

Comment: You're running into "Nested Flex Containers" situation described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/681070. It's confusing. Put `min-width: 0px` on `.hoflex`.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent div `.hoflex` is not assigned with `overflow` property. So by default it will take use `overflow: visible`. You can add `overflow: auto` inside your `.hoflex {overflow: auto;}` property and you will find desired output.

Here is more details on `overflow`

- [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp#:~:text=The%20overflow%20property%20has%20the,renders%20outside%20the%20element's%20box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp#:%7E:text=The%20overflow%20property%20has%20the,renders%20outside%20the%20element%27s%20box)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

The `overflow` property has the following values ([reference w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp#:%7E:text=The%20overflow%20property%20has%20the,renders%20outside%20the%20element%27s%20box)):

- **visible** - Default. The overflow is not clipped. The content renders outside the element's box
- **hidden** - The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible
- **scroll** - The overflow is clipped, and a scrollbar is added to see the rest of the content
- **auto** - Similar to scroll, but it adds scrollbars only when necessary

Try it out here.

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 72px;
  background: darkmagenta;
  color: white;
}

.footer {
  height: 72px;
  background: #eee;
  color: darkmagenta;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  background: royalblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 400px; 
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.hoflex {
  display: flex;
  margin: 16px;
  gap: 12px;
  overflow-x: auto; /* Add this css */
}

.fullflex {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
      MY AWESOME WEBSITE
    </div>
    
    <div class="fullflex">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">⭐ - link one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">‍♂️ - link two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">️ - link three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> - link four</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="hoflex">
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, eveniet? Dolorem dignissimos maiores non delectus possimus dolor nulla repudiandae vitae provident quae, obcaecati ipsam unde impedit corrupti veritatis minima porro?</div>
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi quaerat qui iure ipsam maiores velit tempora, deleniti nesciunt fuga suscipit alias vero rem, corporis officia totam saepe excepturi odit ea.</div>
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
        <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer">
      The Odin Project ❤️
    </div>
```